# My comments for my comment section isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, axios

I'm creating a comment section for my website and in my front end, I want to create a function that displays the comment that the user posted in the database.

But when I created a function that retrieves the comment and display it, the comment won't show up. I don't know what I am doing wrong, did I place it in the wrong place or did I program it correctly?

this is my backend program

```
app.post('/forum', function (req, res){
  const queryString = "INSERT INTO comments (Comments) VALUES (?)"
  console.log (req.body)
  con.query(queryString, [req.body.comment], function (err, result){
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if (result.length != 1) {
      return res.send("Posted Comment")
    }
   else {
     res.send('Comment failed to post')
    };
    })
})

app.get('/forum', function (req, res){
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Comments = ?'
  console.log (req.body)
  con.query(queryString, [req.body.insert], function (err, result){
    if (err) {throw err;}
    var commenting = JSON.stringify(result)
    res.send(commenting);    
  }) 
})
```

the api call that retrieves the response

```
 static async forum(comm){        
      const response = await axios
       .post('http://localhost:8080/forum', {
          comment: comm,
       })    
       .then ()
          return response.data;
           
        
    }

 static async comment(comm){    
        const response = await axios    
          .get('http://localhost:8080/forum', {
             comment: comm
            }) 
          .then ()
            return response.data;   
    }
```

and my frontend where the comment would show up

```
function Forum() {
    
    const [comment, inputComment] = useState ('')
    
    /*user posts the comment*/
    const onPost = (event) => {  
    event.preventDefault()
    apiClient.forum(comment) .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
    }

    /*users comment gets displayed*/
    apiClient.comment() .then((response) =>{
    document.getElementById("comment-section").innerHTML = response
    })

    return (
        <section class = "index-banner" >
            <div>
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id= "comment" rows="10" tabIndex = "4"onChange = {e => {inputComment(e.target.value)}}></textarea>
                <button onClick={onPost}>Post</button>
            </div>            
            <div>
                <body id = "comment-section" ></body>
            </div>
        </section>
    ) 
    
}
```

Comment: why `document.getElementById("comment-section").innerHTML = response` ?

Comment: make then in api call simthing like this `.then((response) => response.json())`

Comment: Why do you use useState like this `const [comment, inputComment] = useState ('')`, you should use like this `const [comment, setcomment] = useState ('')`

Answer (score 0):

Is the request definitely coming through? You can verify in the browser DevTools on the network tab.

A few recommendations I could make about a better way to use React.

1. When the response returns, add it to the component using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> - The component will automatically re-render when there is a state update
> - (here you don't need the `document.getElementById`

2. You could also use the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) approach

> - the favoured "React way" of doing `document.getElementById`

#### 1. with [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

```
function Forum() {
    
    const [comment, setComment] = useState ('')
    const [postedComment, setPostedComment] = useState ('')

    const onPost = (event) => {  
        event.preventDefault()
        apiClient
            .forum(comment)
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                // this should trigger a rerender, in the <div>{postedComment}</div>

                // assuming your response contains the posted comment:
                setPostedComment(response.data)
            })
            .catch( error => console.log(error) /* handle Exception here */)
    }
    
    return <div>
        <label>Comment</label>
        <textarea
            name="comment"
            id="comment"
            rows="10"
            tabIndex ="4"
            onChange={e => {inputComment(e.target.value)}}>
         </textarea>
    
         <button onClick={onPost}>Post</button>
        <div>{ postedComment }</div>
</div>            
}
```

#### 2. with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
    const commentRef = useRef(null)
    // ...

    const onPost = (event) => {  
        event.preventDefault()
        apiClient
            .forum(comment)
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                // assuming your response contains the posted comment:
                commentRef.current.innerHTML = response
            })
            .catch( error => console.log(error) /* handle Exception here */)
    }
    


    return <div>
        {/* ... */}
        <div ref={commentRef}>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> NOTES:
>
> - I would avoid using the `body` element except for the entire application!
>
> To address some of the comments:
>
> - [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) uses `response.json()`
> - [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) uses `response.data`

Comment: You are right but I'm not sure that of `response.json()` axios is use for requesting the api and  `static async comment(comm)` is returning `response.data`, so  I think that`setPostedComment(response)`  is enough.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue @antoineso I updated the code sample. Let me know if all is good and you approve of my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I added two api calls. apiClient.forum posts the comment into the database and apiClient.comment selects the posted comment from the database.                                                                                                                                                                I edited my post so I can show you the full code from both my api client and backend to give you the idea. sorry if I didn't make it clear

Comment: @AmmanM regardless of how your API works now, I'm wondering if the answer helped you get past your question, which was to display the fetched data? I.e. my suggestions on `useState` and `useRef`. This POST is meant to help people with similar problems to the one you had, regardless of the API being used. Please let me know if you approve and please upvote the proposed answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: @bilo-io I tried using some of the methods you recommended me but the comments aren't showing up. Maybe it's the way I typed the code but thank you for the suggestions anyway